# Add a way to limit number of lines in secondary text by using material ui v1

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-design, material-ui

Please let me know if there is any solution available for this. Its a general question so i don't have any working example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with `rowsMax` property, you need to have `multiline` enabled. See section Props for more info : https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/#textfield

Comment: I am looking for List item secondary text

Comment: So I don't know if you can, not in the docs. So you can try something like this with css : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow. Hope this help !